How are the locations in the select your location screen in the debian installation categorized?
I have to select a location in order to install Debian. 18 locations can be chosen on the first page of the selection. Others are available when selecting other. Which logic determines if a location is on the first page of the selection or categorized as other?

The process is described in the localechooser README:

the first screen asks the user to choose a language
the second screen (with eighteen selections in English) lists all the supported locales using that language
“other” leads to a third screen providing access to all the locales

The logic determining whether a location appears in the second screen (the first page you mention) is whether the corresponding locale is supported by the C library. If you install locales-all, you can run locale -a to verify this: in English (en), the supported locales are en_AG, en_AU, en_BW, en_CA, en_DK, en_GB, en_HK, en_IE, en_IL, en_IN, en_NG, en_NZ, en_PH, en_SC, en_SG, en_US, en_ZA, en_ZM, and zn_ZW; after excluding en_DK (for somewhat complex reasons), this matches the list of countries in the selection screen.
The whole process is slightly more complicated than that; for example languages with a single country don’t ask the user to choose a country, and some languages (such as Danish) ask the user to choose among all the countries in the relevant geographical region rather than countries with supported locales using that language. See the linked README for details.
